# replacing data in between specific characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string which has some keys between <<>>.

```
 string s = "<p>Hi <<USER>>,<br/>How are you doing<br/>Regards,<br/><<SENDER>></p>";
```

I want to first fetch the key names USER and SENDER in a list which i did by:

```
    var keys = new List<string>();
            foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(s, @"<<(.*?)>>")) 
            {
                keys.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);

            }
List<string> values= new List<string>(){"John","Team"};
```

After we get the keys,i want to replace these keys by another list(named values here) which has the values for these keys and want the result as:

```
 string s = "<p>Hi John,<br/>How are you doing<br/>Regards,<br/>Team</p>";
```

The string `s` can be anything and the no of keys and their values could also vary but the keys will always be enclosed in between <<>>

Comment: Is there a specific problem you'd like help with?

Comment: @GrantWinney: Yes you are correct, there can be any number of placeholders but all of them will be enclosed between <<>>,The no. of strings in 'values' will be equal to the no of strings in 'keys' by default  any  i need to replace the first placeholder with the first string in values, so that the string 's' in  the first line gets converted to string 's' at the last line.

Comment: @GrantWinney: * i need to replace the first placeholder with the first string in values and second with second and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @AlexBell, you could simply use the `String.Replace()` method.
Further, it's more convenient to declare a collection of *placeholder/value* pairs, like so:

```
string s = "<p>Hi <<USER>>,<br/>How are you doing<br/>Regards,<br/><<SENDER>></p>";

Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictionary.Add("<<USER>>", "Jhon");
dictionary.Add("<<SENDER>>", "Team");

StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(s);
foreach (var entry in dictionary)
{
    text.Replace(entry.Key, entry.Value);
}

Console.WriteLine(text.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

This function will perform the replacements that you ask for, using [Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static string ParseTemplate(string template, string username, string senderName)
{
    template = Regex.Replace(template, @"<<USER>>", username);
    return Regex.Replace(template, @"<<SENDER>>", senderName);
}
```

Example:

```
string s = "<p>Hi <<USER>>,<br/>How are you doing<br/>Regards,<br/><<SENDER>></p>";
ParseTemplate(s, "John", "Team").Dump();
```

Output:

> <p>Hi John,<br/>How are you doing<br/>Regards,<br/>Team</p>

You can call this in a loop over your dictionary or list of names.

Answer (score 0):

Your business logic is a bit unclear, so based on just qualified guess, you can apply standard .NET/C#  `String.Replace` Method (String, String) 
(re:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for example:

```
string s = "<p>Hi <<USER>>,<br/>How are you doing<br/>Regards,<br/><<SENDER>></p>".Replace("<USER>", "John").Replace("<SENDER>", "Team");
```

Hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

```
//First we have lists of values (users) and senders
List<string> values= new List<string>(){"John","Team"};
List<string> senders = new List<string>(){"John","Team"};
//Then we can join that list using string.join
var allUsers = string.Join(",", values);
var allSender = string.Join(",", senders);

//Next we will be replacing it in our string
var namedString = Regex.Replace(string, @"<<USER>>", allUsers);
var output = Regex.Replace(namedString , @"<<SENDER>>", allSender);
```